# Relationship between spring constant and amplitude in vertical spring-mass system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, harmonic-oscillator, spring

> Two objects of equal mass hang from independent springs of unequal spring constant and oscillate up and down. The spring of greater spring constant must have the
>
> (A) smaller amplitude of oscillation
>
> (B) larger amplitude of oscillation
>
> (C) shorter period of oscillation
>
> (D) longer period of oscillation
>
> (E) lower frequency of oscillation

I know, for sure, that greater spring constant results in shorter period of oscillation, for period is inversely related to square root of spring constant.

However, I am uncertain if the amplitude of oscillation is unrelated to the spring constant.

From energy perspective, let $A$ denote the amplitude. From $mg = kd$ we know that $d = \frac{mg}{k}$. Then
\begin{gather}
mgA = \frac{1}{2}k(A-d)^2, \\
mgA = \frac{1}{2}k\left(A^2 - 2 A \left(\frac{mg}{k}\right) + \left(\frac{mg}{k}\right)^2\right), \\
\frac{1}{2}k A^2 - 2 m g A + \frac{m^2 g^2}{2k} = 0, \\
A = \frac{2mg \pm \sqrt{4m^2 g^2 - m^2 g^2}}{k}.
\end{gather}

Hence, greater spring constant results in smaller amplitude.

Please indicate any mistakes.

Much gratitude for your attention.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/168783), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead.

Comment: Also, please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amplitude depends on the initial conditions. For example if I start with a stationary mass and pull it down a distance $x$ and let go then it will oscillate with an amplitude of $x$. This does not depend on the spring constant $k$.

There are situations where the spring constant could have an effect on the amplitude because it affects the initial conditions. For example suppose I pull the mass down by exerting some force $F$ that is the same for all the springs. The initial displacement would then be $x = F/k$, and hence the amplitude of the oscillations would be inversely proportional to $k$. However this is only true because I imposed the initial condition that the force be constant. In general there is no simple relationship between the spring constant and the amplitude of the oscillation.

Comment: Can't thank you more. Thanks for your brilliant explanation.